# Javascript async function console log the returned data

Tags: javascript, json, function, asynchronous, return

How can I console log - or do any thing with the data returned from inside an async function?

example:
JS FILE:

```
   async function getData(){
      try {
         $.getJSON('./data.json', (data) => {
            return data;
         });
      } catch(error) {
         console.log("error" + error);
      } finally {
         console.log('done');
      }
   }

   console.log(getData());
```

JSON FILE:

```
{
   "stuff": {
      "First": {
         "FirstA": {
            "year": [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
            "Categories": ["Suspension", "Electrical", "Performance", "Motor"]
         },
         "FirstB": {
            "year": [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
            "Categories": ["Suspension", "Electrical", "Performance", "Motor"]
         }
      },
      "Second": {
         "SecondA": {
            "year": [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006],
            "Categories": ["Suspension", "Electrical", "Performance", "Motor"]
         },
         "SecondB": {
            "year": [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
            "Categories": ["Suspension", "Electrical", "Performance", "Motor"]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How can I return / get access to all the information in the JSON file and work with it. for example I'd like to take the "First" and "Second" and add them to a div. Same with "FirstA" and "FirstB" and "SecondA" and "SecondB"...and so on.

Right now as it stands, I get ***Promise {: undefined}***

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---------UPDATE---------

If I run the console log inside the function I then can see the json data, but I need access to the data outside the function.

Serge

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Two issues:

1. To **set** the resolution value of the promise created by the `async` function, you have to use a `return` statement from the `async` function itself. Your code has a `return` in the `getJSON` callback (which is ignored), not the `async` function itself.
2. To **get** the resolution value of an `async` function, you must `await` it (or consume its promise in the older way, via `then`, etc.).

For #1, you could return the result of `await`ing `getJSON`:

```
async function getData() {
    try {
        return await $.getJSON('./data.json').promise();
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error" + error);
    }
    finally {
        console.log('done');
    }
}
```

And for #2, you'd need to either `await` your function (this would, in turn, need to be inside an `async`function):

```
console.log(await getData());
```

...or consume its promise via `then`:

```
getData().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

Side note: Your `getData` hides errors, turning them into resolutions with the value `undefined`, which is generally not a good idea. Instead, ensure that it propagates the error:

```
catch (error) {
    console.log("error" + error);
    throw error;
}
```

Then, naturally, ensure that anything using `getData` either handles or propagates the error, making sure something somewhere *does* handle it (otherwise, you get an "unhandled rejection" error).

---

Re your comment

> how would I access the "stuff" in the json file from the log outside the function?

The async result / resolution value of `getData` is the object the JSON defined (it's no longer JSON, it's been parsed). So you'd use `.stuff` on it, e.g.:

```
// In an `async` function
console.log((await getData()).stuff);

// Or using `then`:
getData().then(data => {
    console.log(data.stuff);
});
```

Comment: T.J. Crowder in the first example what is the "i" in the i.getJSON and where is it coming from? I know I am sprinkling some jQuery in there with the getJSON method, but just testing to see if this would work.

Comment: @Sergio: It was a typo (now fixed). Which is odd, given that I used copy and paste. So maybe not a typo, but rather an editing error. :-)

Comment: hahaha...it's no biggie. Ok, just tested and now something is happening.

Comment: now how would I access the "stuff" in the json file from the log outside the function? I tried console.log(getData().stuff); and I get undefined.

Comment: @Sergio: Yes, of course you do, because `getData` returns a promise, and promises don't have a property called `stuff`. I've added to the end of the answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help. Using the .then method worked for me. the await kept giving me an error of Unexpected identifier

Comment: @Sergio: No worries. Yes. As I said above, you can only use `await` in an `async` function.

Comment: aahh... so the "await" can only be used inside the async function. Outside the async function "then" should be used - as you clearly commented out in your example lol.

Comment: T.J. I have a follow-up question posted here...if you can, can you take a look at it. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036910/javascript-async-function-inside-jquery-on-change-function-returns-undefined

Comment: with arrow function you could just do `async () => console.log(await getData())`

Answer (score 0):

I use following way. Create a async function like following:

```
private consoleLogAsync = async (message: string, other?: any) => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0)).then(() => console.info(message, other));
};
```

Use it in your async function where you want to log e.g.:

```
 await this.consoleLogAsync('myMessage', myObject);
```