# Javascript async function inside jQuery on Change function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, asynchronous

How can I call an async function inside a jQuery .change function? I have tried the following and it returns me "undefined"...

```
async function getData(){
      try {
         return await $.getJSON('./data.json').promise();
      } catch(error) {
         console.log("error" + error);
         throw error;
      } finally {
         alert("done");
      }
   }
```

Here an example of the JSON:

```
{
   "stuff": {
      "First": {
         "FirstA": {
            "year": [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
            "Categories": ["Suspension", "Electrical", "Performance", "Motor"]
         },
         "FirstB": {
            "year": [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
            "Categories": ["Suspension", "Electrical", "Performance", "Motor"]
         }
      },
      "Second": {
         "SecondA": {
            "year": [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006],
            "Categories": ["Suspension", "Electrical", "Performance", "Motor"]
         },
         "SecondB": {
            "year": [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
            "Categories": ["Suspension", "Electrical", "Performance", "Motor"]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And Here is the jQuery function:

```
$('select[name="make"]').change(function(){

      // THIS LET RETURNS EITHER First or Second
      let makeSelected = $('select[name="make"] option:selected').val();

      getData().then(data => {
         let topModels = data.stuff;

         // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
         console.log(topModels.makeSelected);

         // THIS RETURNS THE CORRECT DATA
         console.log(topModels.First);
      });

   });
```

How come the let variable does not work for the first console.log?

Comment: What happens if you just console.log topModels?

Comment: @CharlieFish I get the expected data as well.

Comment: Well `topModels` doesn't have a property `makeSelected`.

Comment: You should use `topModels[makeSelected]`

Comment: right, but I would assume that the variable value would take its place ie.: First or Second...no?

Comment: @Sergio What do you mean?

Comment: @Axnyff How would that help??? `topModels` doesn't have a property `makeSelected`

Comment: He wants to access the property whose key is the value of makeSelected: `topModels[makeSelected]`, note `topModels["makeSelected"]`

Comment: @Axnyff that actually works... seems weird to use [ ] to access an object property instead of a .(dot)

Comment: The dot notation is a shortcut: a.method is the same as a["method"]

Comment: aaahh... never knew that. Can the dot and square bracket notation be used interchangeably in arrays and objects?

Comment: @CharlieFish: `topModels[makeSelected]` isn't looking for a property called `makeSelected` on `topModels`. It's looking for a property whose name is the **value** of `makeSelected` in `topModels`. E.g.: `var u = {answer: 42}; var name = "answer"; console.log(u[name]); // 42`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything should work fine, but you are acessing a property ("makeSelected") that doesn't exist on the "data.stuff". By using `data.stuff.makeSelected` that's what you're asking for. Now, if what you intent to do is to look for a property with the name equal to the value inside the variable "makeSelected", you have 2 main paths to choose from:

1) Use "eval": You can build a string just like `let str = "data.stuff."+makeSelected; let result = eval(str);`

2) You could use the `[]` notation to access an JS object properties, just like `let result = data.stuff[makeSelection];` which is my prefered solution.

Comment: #2 worked perfectly for me. Thanks.